# Burninate the [data] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[data](/questions/tagged/data) is way too broad and doesn't really give meaning to questions. It definitely doesn't sound like something you can be an expert on.

Can / should it be burninated?

Comment: pulverise, puree, nuke, blend, Justin-Beiberise, nuke again (to sterilise it), and anti-matter-annihilate it

Comment: @UV-D I personally thought "deleted", "removed" or even "eradicated" would have been acceptable

Comment: @davblayn true, but there is something to be said to being thorough

Comment: @UV-D could you please provide a cost-benefit analysis to see whether nuking the tag twice is a viable approach. Also, [this](http://thesaurus.com/browse/Destroy) might be useful

Comment: Eight mofuggen grand questions.  I believe I have spotted my windmill.